# Kusto- SCAN Operator

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am new to Kusto Query and trying to understand how SCAN operator works step by step. I searched online but very few documentation is available at present for this topic. Explanation on MS Site is also not very useful(for me). Could you please help in this regard by posting an article for the same or suggest some documentation which I can refer.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following article useful: [SCAN Operator: Process Mining in Azure Data Explorer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/the-new-scan-operator-process-mining-in-azure-data-explorer/ba-p/2378795)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked this article but it is more about the implementation. It doesn't tell how the records are travelling or taking shape among the steps/state.  Also, only two articles are available online for Kusto SCAN Operator. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Also, documentation says "Steps are evaluated from last to first". Is that mean if SCAN have 3 steps (step1, step2,step3), step3 will be evaluated first then step2 and step1 ? Or it is just each step evaluation from Right to Left ?

Comment: The records are fed in sequential order. If a record matches a step it overrides the record that is currently in the step. Each time the first step is empty, and a record matches it, a new sequence (with its match id) is started. The reason the steps are scanned from last to first is because we prefer to move a specific sequence to the next step in order to enable starting a new sequence (from the first step) in parallel to the existing sequence(s). Best if you describe your use case and we can try to help you build the correct scan for it

Comment: Dear Adi E, Thanks for your reply.
Below is the code Snippet (taken from MS SCAN document Site with some change). If you could explain how the records are taking shape. ->
let Events = datatable ( Ts: timespan, Event: string ) 
[0m,"A",1m,"A",2m,"B",3m,"D",32m,"B",36m,"C",38m,"D",41m,"E",75m,"A"];
Events
|sort by Ts asc
|scan with_match_id=session_id declare (sessionStart:timespan) with 
(step inSession: true => sessionStart = iff(isnull(inSession.sessionStart), Ts, inSession.sessionStart);
step endSession output=all: Ts - inSession.sessionStart > 30m;)